# Use package.json version in MD files for Vue Press

Tags: vuepress

I'm trying to utilise the package.json version tag inside of my `*.md` files which get later compiled into HTML, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this. My plugin.js files contains the following which I thought I could utilise:

```js
const { version } = require('../../package.json')

module.exports = (/*options, ctx*/) => ({
  async enhanceAppFiles () {
    const code = `export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
      $version () {
        return '${version}'
      } 
    }
  })
}`
    return [{
      name: 'vuepress-plugin-vue-cli-plugin-p11n',
      content: code
    }]
  }
})
```

I tried using `version` and `$version` inside of my `*.md` files with little luck, has anyone else got this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this, it's simply put the `version` into `themeConfig` and let VuePress do its thing

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
const { version } = require('../../package')

module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    version: version
  }
}
```

and use it [in markdown](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-vue-in-markdown) like

```
{{ $themeConfig.version }}
```

However, it seems like that `themeConfig` isn't meant for this, so you can also create your own computed properties

```js
// .vuepress/enhanceApp.js
const { version } = require('../../package')

export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
      $version: function() {
        return version
      }
    }
  })
}
```

and use it like

```
{{ $version }}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! These both work, however it looks like it was working before, and I've just realised, I'm trying to use `{{ $themeConfig.version }}` within a code block, using the back ticks, the black sh sections, is this still possible? How could I get it here.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you. Basically, you want to use `{{}}` syntax inside a code block? I don't think it's possible. I mean, the point of a code block is to display the code as it is, right? However, I think you can try to customize a [container](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#custom-containers) or create a component to achieve that